# Decipher the message in the 31x31 grid

Tags: nonogram

You have been given a blank 31 x 31 grid as shown below. Each square in the grid is either "light" or "dark".

The numbers to the right of the grid represent the consecutive sequences of "light" squares in each row while the numbers in the bottom represent the consecutive sequence of "light" squares in each vertical column.

[image]

---

For those interested in text (edited to fix line breaks).

Rows:

```
1 3 2 2 2 2 3 1
1 3 1 3 1 3 1 3 1 3 1
1 3 1 3 1 3 1 3 2 1 2
1 1 1 2 4 3
1 3 1 3 1 5 7 3
1 3 1 3 1 5 7 3
1 3 1 3 1 5 7 3
31
7 3 1 1 3 7
7 3 1 5 3 7
7 2 1 5 3 7
7 2 2 2 2 1 1 7
7 2 1 5 1 1 7
7 3 1 5 1 1 7
7 3 1 2 1 8
31
4 3 1 2 2 5
4 3 1 5 3 1 3 4
5 1 2 5 3 3 4
6 3 5 3 1 1 6
6 3 5 3 1 2 5
6 3 1 3 1 3 5
6 3 1 3 1 3 4
31
5 3 3 4 7
4 3 1 3 1 3 9
8 1 3 1 3 9
7 2 1 1 2 2 7
6 3 2 2 2 3 6
5 4 2 2 3 6
4 2 2 2 7
```

Columns:

```
31
24
3 27
3 27
3 12 7 4
11 5 4
19 1 3 1
1 1 3 5 2 2
2 6 5 7 3
2 7 19
2 8 3 2 1
1 1 1 2 2 1 3 1
16 2 2 1 2 2
1 1 2 2 1 1 3
2 4 2 2 1 5 2 1
2 4 2 2 16
2 4 2 2 2 2 4
1 5 5 1 2 4
16 2 10
1 2 2 11
2 10 2 3 1
2 7 11 1 2
2 10 1 1 2 2
1 5 2 2 4 2 2
16 2 7 1
17 2 1 9
2 14 3 8
3 24
2 28
29
31
```

Hint

> For example, a 31 to the right of the grid means that all the squares in that row are "light" colored.

Comment: Plugging into a nonagrams solver tells me "The sum of row data is 1 more than the sum of column data." Is this intended?

Comment: also, the text has a couple rows of data grouped together without required line breaks (those three lines that are noticeably longer than the others)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pretty sure the answer is

> Happy new year 2016
>  [image]
>
>   Like others have mentioned tough, numbers weren't entire correct, as you can see from the broken r and weird 6.

Comment: so close...  pretty sure you're a little off.

Comment: @ElGuapo could be 2016 ;)

Answer (score 4):

Although some of the items were off by a little, I think this is what you were aiming for:

> [image]

By "off by a little", I mean that row 12 doesn't exactly look good as you posted, so I took a little artistic license, and modified it.
Instead of 7 2 2 2 2 1 1 7, it should have been 7 1 1 1 2 1 1 7.  There may have been more small errors like that, but once I got started I was able to finish it mostly without using the numbers.

Comment: Great job !!! Thanks for being quick !!!